# Is CoD:BlackOps cheat-proof on consoles?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I have read about a couple of tools which allow you to cheat on Call of Duty: Black Ops on a PC. Are such tools also available for PS3 or XBox-360, or can we say that consoles are cheat-proof?

Comment: Is anything at all cheat-proof?

Comment: Are you asking because you want to cheat...?

Comment: No, I'm trying to figure out which platform is safer to play.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While [hacks are possible](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/forum/240-bo-modding/), you should be aware that playing online with modded consoles or hacked games is likely to get your account and/or console banned. Microsoft in particular [does not look kindly on cheats](http://whywasibanned.com/).

Comment: There's been a recent influx of cowards on Wii multiplayer

Answer (score 2):

At least, "cheating" by using a lag-switch is possible, so this question about lag-witching here wich may be interesting for you: [What's the best way to beat a lag switcher?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22196/whats-the-best-way-to-beat-a-lag-switcher)

Answer (score 0):

Consoles are not safe. Even here not so long ago there was question related to X360 BO cheaters: [What's the best way to beat a lag switcher?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22196/whats-the-best-way-to-beat-a-lag-switcher)

What makes matter worse, there are no dedicated servers on consoles, thus no server admins, and server kick/bans.